# How to debug a play framework 2.2.5 application in eclipse ide?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, playframework-2.5

I am new to play framework.I want to debug my application in eclipse.I tried with some solutions using google search.But it does not helps me.Please tell me how to debug a play application in eclipse and at production level also.For all help thanks in advance.

Comment: Which solutions did you try and what specifically went wrong?

Comment: Need more details here, especially as @showdev suggests, about what you have tried.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes the person needs to help themselves first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone they know who can help them. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious mistakes, and get it re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SBT to compile and run my Scala Play application, if you are as well, this might help you.
What I do is on command line set `SBT_OPTS` like so:

```
set SBT_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9999
```

Then when you `sbt run` it will wait for a debugger to attach on socket port 9999.

I use the [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/) to develop and debug my application.
In after you've run `sbt run` you attach the Scala IDE by creating a new `Remote Java Application` debug configuration specifying `Scala debugger (Socket Attach)` and setting the port to `9999` (host should be `localhost` by default). Then click on debug and you should be up and debugging.